# Wrong animation when using navigation architecture component

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am building an app that uses BottomNavigationView and Navigation Architecture Component (https://github.com/fkshiba/POCNavigation).
I have one graph.xml for each tab and the transition between tabs is done by the [Activity](https://github.com/fkshiba/POCNavigation/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/felipeshiba/pocnavigation/NavigationActivity.kt) without Navigation AC due to the multiple backstack [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80029773). I have an action with a transition animation on [home_graph.xml](https://github.com/fkshiba/POCNavigation/blob/master/app/src/main/res/navigation/home_graph.xml) from Home2 to Home3.
The problem is, once I run this transition and pop back to Home2 then navigate to another tab. It runs the pop animation again for the Home2 fragment when I transition from another tab even though there wasn't any animation specified for it.

Does anyone know a solution for this issue?

Comment: It's a problem inside FragmentManager, there's an issue opened for it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121017790

Answer (score 0):

I see your code on GitHub and i assume that you are using android navigation wrongly. First you don't need to create different graphs(in your case four) for 
different fragments. Just create one graph and add all fragments in it that you have to use within your bottom navigation and for others transactions.
And secondly you don't need to perform fragment transactions manually (in your activity code) you can but not necessary.
Your updated code:
only one graph:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/home_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/home2Fragment">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/home2Fragment"
    android:name="com.felipeshiba.pocnavigation.Home2Fragment"
    android:label="fragment_home2"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home2" >
    <action
            android:id="@+id/action_home2Fragment_to_home3Fragment"
            app:destination="@id/home3Fragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim"/>
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/home3Fragment"
    android:name="com.felipeshiba.pocnavigation.Home3Fragment"
    android:label="fragment_home3"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home3" >
    <deepLink
        android:id="@+id/deepLink"
        app:uri="ifood://home/" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/orders2Fragment"
    android:name="com.felipeshiba.pocnavigation.Orders2Fragment"
    android:label="fragment_orders2"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_orders2" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/profile2Fragment"
    android:name="com.felipeshiba.pocnavigation.Profile2Fragment"
    android:label="fragment_profile2"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile2" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/search2Fragment"
    android:name="com.felipeshiba.pocnavigation.Search2Fragment"
    android:label="fragment_search2"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search2" /></navigation>
```

Your updated activity code:

```
class NavigationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation)
    val host: NavHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_container) as NavHostFragment? ?: return

    val navController = host.navController
    bottom_navigation.setupWithNavController(navController)

}}
```

Now you can just call your botton navigation items(fragments) within your menu by replacing menu item id with fragments id like below:
updated menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/home2Fragment"
    android:icon="?android:attr/actionModeCopyDrawable"
    android:title="Home" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/search2Fragment"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="Search" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/orders2Fragment"
    android:icon="?android:attr/actionModePasteDrawable"
    android:title="Orders" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/profile2Fragment"
    android:icon="?android:attr/actionModeCutDrawable"
    android:title="Profile" /></menu>
```

Your activity.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".NavigationActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_container"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/home_graph"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"></android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

For other updated(working) code like manifest check [here](https://github.com/haidar786/POCNavigation-master)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it navigates to the startDestination whenever I select a tab. If I navigate from Home2 to Home3 and select Search tab and then the Home tab, it goes back to Home2. That's not what I want.

Comment: OK I can fix it using nested graph just wait.

Comment: I'm sorry i search a lot but can't find solution because android architecture components does not work like that. They must have a start destination so i think you have to do this pro grammatically.

Comment: There must be a good solution for that but i didn't find yet.

Answer (score 0):

NavigationUI will always pop to start destination before going to other tab in BottomNavigationView, it's just how the nav lib works. Set custom OnNavigationItemSelectedListener and navigate yourself, and pass your animations through NavOptions.